# Why isn't this valid html?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, paypal

Whenever I add this code into my exisiting code, I'm getting an error that the 'row','regOptButtons' and the first 'col-sm-6' div aren't closed. But if I insert that section in a blank HTML document, there are no errors

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="regOptButtons">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="form align-center">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxx">
        <input type="submit" title="PayPal" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-clr" value="Register and Pay Deposit">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="form registration-form align-center">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxx">
        <input type="submit" title="PayPal" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-clr" value="Register and Pay in Full">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: may be use missed the top div closing

Comment: which editor you are using ?

Comment: dreamweaver, but online validators say the same thing

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: yes, ' <!doctype html> '

Comment: can you provide your source code ?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. Check the half-dozen or so lines above what is shown here. This fragment is perfectly valid HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of everyone's comments, I found my issue. The paypal buttons are actually forms. I was trying to put those buttons inside of another form. You can't put a form inside of a form. Once I moved them to another place, it worked well. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You're welcome. It has been our pleasure to help you out